# Unable to set properties of tableview through segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UIContainerView` that is hooked up to a custom `UITableViewController`. In storyboards, I set up a grouped table view with static cells. Each static cell has a text field in it, and it is hooked up to an IBOutlet on the table view controller's header. They are also synthesized. In the parent view controller, where the container resides, I use the `prepareForSegue` method, to set the values of the outlets like this:

```
 SOModuleInfoTable* infoTable = (SOModuleInfoTable*)[segue destinationViewController];
           infoTable.tf_name.text = @"test";
```

However, the text fields are empty when the view loads. Any help would be much appreciated. Also, this segue is fired, I checked with logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is timing. The prepareForSegue method is called before viewDidLoad of the child is called, so tf_name will be null at the time you try to set the text to "test". Instead, you should have a string property in the table view controller, and set the value of that property to "test" in prepareForSegue. Then, in viewDidLoad of the table view controller, use that string to populate your label.