# How to pass a label through segue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, segue

I have a utility application for iOS that I am building. It's an anagram game that tracks how many times the user guesses, guesses correctly, and guesses incorrectly. I keep track of how many times the guesses are (in)correct and want to display the data on the flipside view controller. However, with the following code, nothing is changing when the segue occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `AnagramsMainViewController.m`:

```
#import "AnagramsMainViewController.h"


@interface AnagramsMainViewController ()

@end

@implementation AnagramsMainViewController

@synthesize jumbledWord, jumbledWordLabel, unjumbledWord, unjumbledWordLabel, textField, statusLabel, timesGuessed, timesGuessedCorrect, timesGuessedIncorrect;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(AnagramsFlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
         AnagramsFlipsideViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
        controller.timesGuessedCorrectLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Times guessed correct: %d", timesGuessedCorrect];
        controller.timesGuessedIncorrectLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Times guessed incorrect: %d", timesGuessedIncorrect];
        controller.totalTimesGuessedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total times guessed: %d", timesGuessed];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Here is my `AnagramsFlipsideViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AnagramsFlipsideViewController;

@protocol AnagramsFlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(AnagramsFlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface AnagramsFlipsideViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <AnagramsFlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *totalTimesGuessedLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timesGuessedCorrectLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timesGuessedIncorrectLabel;


- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

(I have synthesized these labels in `AnagramsFlipsideViewController.m`)

Comment: Look at my answer here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863542/unable-to-set-properties-of-tableview-through-segue/20864395#20864395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is trying to set the contents of views in another view controller. Don't do that.

It violates the encapsulation of the other view controller, so it's a bad idea from an Object Oriented Design perspective, and it also sometimes just doesn't work (like in this case.)

Instead, create NSString or NSInteger properties for the values you need to pass (e.g. totalTimesGuessed, timesGuessedCorrect, timesGuessedInCorrect, and set **THOSE** in your prepareForSegue method.

Then in your AnagramsFlipsideViewController's viewWillAppear method, take those string values and install them in your labels.

Comment: You make a good point, that is exactly what I was doing wrong. Thank you for your help. Here's how I fixed it for anyone else wondering:

1. Created 3 `NSString` properties in my flipside view controller
2. Set the value of the 3 `NSString`s to what I want to pass
3. In the `viewDidLoad` method of the flipside view controller, set the values of the `UILabel`s to the `NSString`s that I passed over.

Comment: It is probably better to set the labels in viewWillAppear rather than ViewDidLoad. In the case where you create a view controller and display it, it doesn't really matter, but if you have a view controller that displays another view controller, then gets updated information from second VC, viewWillAppear would be called again when the second VC goes away, but viewDidLoad will not.